# "Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'data'" in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm a novice swift/xcode'r and and am having some issues.  I'm using tutorials to learn how to code and one of the issues I'm having is with the code below. I have pasted the "above and below" code of it for context.  can someone help out a noob?

In this code:

```
ref.data(MaxSize: 1000000, completion: { (data, error) in.
```

I get the following error:

> Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'data'

But I have no clue how to change it.

```
func configCell(searchDetail: Search) {

        self.searchDetail = searchDetail

        nameLbl.text = searchDetail.username

        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: searchDetail.userImg)

        ref.data(MaxSize: 1000000, completion: { (data, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("we couldnt upload the img")

            } else {

                if let imgData = data {

                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {

                        self.userImage.image = img
                    }
```

Comment: Try  ref.getData(MaxSize: 1000000 instead of *ref.data*. Also, as a side note, you are passing *searchDetail* into this function and then assigning it to a class variable - I don't know the rest of the code but there's probably no reason to do that. If you assign the class variable up front *self.searchDetail* you can use it throughout the class (if that's your use case)

Comment: great!  thank you so much for your help!